# how to se t the right click operations of a link in qtwebkit

Tags: qt

[How to edit QtWebKit's right-click context menu in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327222/how-to-edit-qtwebkits-right-click-context-menu-in-qt-creator)
[how to get response in QtWebKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426053/how-to-get-response-in-qtwebkit)
https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/15149/
i have seen all these threads and more but cant get my anwser
i want to set the righ click menu of links images frames etc. in qtwebkit
in qwebview
i have heard that we have to install an event filter and get the object which is at that position but i am not geting it
can you tell me a simple and sweet solution
tell how to set the operation of that action
also iut would be great if you can give a sample live working code
i have heard that we have to use QMenu and QAction for this.

Answer (score 1):

To get a "standard" menu from QWebView based upon where you clicked, do:

```
    page()->updatePositionDependentActions(pos);
    QMenu* ctxMenu = page()->createStandardContextMenu();
```

to know on what you clicked, use

```
QWebHitTestResult hit = page()->mainFrame()->hitTestContent(pressPoint.toPoint());
```

Comment: https://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/79009/ the final solution written by me with your and others help and by experimenting a lot i have been busy in experimenting these days

Comment: Would using the position argument work if the context menu was invoked using the keyboard instead of the mouse?